# Automatically generate google-services.json for Android flavor

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-build, google-play-services

I have an app which I need to add different flavors, and each flavor must have the google-services.json file from firebase. 
It means that now I manually register a new application, download the json file and put it in the flavor project (folder).

Is there any API for registering the flavor app (different package name) manually, 
downloading it, and put it in the correct folder, during the gradle build process, by using gradle tasks?

Comment: It is possible to have single `google-services.json` file which contains details for multiple "apps"....another option I've used is to create `FirebaseApp` instance dynamically.

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply, but my question was how to do the register process automatically? can you give more details about the second option? :)

Comment: More details on second option in answer below.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using `google-services.json` (and associated gradle plugin) you can create `FirebaseApp` instance dynamically using something like:

```
    FirebaseOptions firebaseOptions = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setApiKey(apiKey)
            .setApplicationId(context.getString(R.string.google_app_id))
            .setDatabaseUrl(databaseUrl)
            .setStorageBucket(storageBucket)
            .build();

    FirebaseApp firebaseApp = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context, firebaseOptions, "MyApp");
```

Comment: thanks! I'll try it! but is there something that may enable this process during the build gradle? I mean some gradle tasks?

Comment: yes, you can customise values used in your `build.gradle` file e.g. I'm using `resValue 'string', 'google_app_id', googleAppId` to set the app id string used above.